# Is it possible to plot different topics on the same plot in rxbag?

Tags: ros, rxbag, rxtools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have several distinct topics saved in a bag and I would like to plot them on the same plot for comparison purposes in rxbag. This works great for values in the same topic, but I don't know if I can do this for different topics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10529/is-it-possible-to-plot-different-topics-on-the-same-plot-in-rxbag?/) by [cmansley](https://answers.ros.org/users/803/cmansley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2011-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For plotting you can use [rxplot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxplot). You can plot any numeric value from any plot. You will be able to plot them in the same plot, or separated plots but in the same screen. Have a look at the documentation since it is very easy to use.

I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) with karma: 219 on 2011-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) on 2011-07-21**:
Playing bag files and using rxplot could be a good alternative. If not, have a look at http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxbag_plugins I haven't used it but it seems it can help you.

**Comment by [cmansley](https://answers.ros.org/users/803/cmansley/) on 2011-07-21**:
I know about rxplot, but I have bag files. Are you suggesting that I have to play the bag files back to get the functionality of rxplot, when there is a tool rxbag designed for viewing and plotting data in bag files? I just want to plot two topics to the same plot (not even the same graph).